# Изменение модификатора доступа при переопределении

Tags: java, ооп

Вопрос задавался на собеседовании:
"Возможно ли при переопределении метода изменить модификатор доступа?"
При ответе, что изменить можно, но при условии его расширения (package private -> protected -> public) прозвучал встречный вопрос: "А почему так?"
???
Понятно, что если нарушить это условие, то будет ошибка на стадии компиляции. Возможно чтобы ответить на этот вопрос нужны более глубокие познания в ООП? Если у кого есть соображения...

Comment: ну на самом деле всё просто) в Java все функции виртуальные. Нету смысла делать функцию в наследнике менее открытой, потому что она всё равно может быть вызвана через базовый класс. (фундаментальное свойство и получается бред). А вот расширить можно. Тогда вызывать нужно будет например через каст. Хотя тоже попахивает кривой архитектурой. (коммент потому что не уверен в правильности).

Comment: кстати в С++ такое делать можно. https://ideone.com/DDQN8q (но смысла мало). Поэтому ответ скорее мало зависит от ООП концепций, просто в Java так удобнее делать вызовы методов.

Comment: То есть, получается, это будет противоречить основному принципу полиморфизма?

Comment: да. Если вы передадите наследника то у него всё равно будет вызван приватный метод по полиморфизму.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Принцип подстановки Лисков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Там, где допустимо использовать тип Х, должно быть допустимо использовать и любой тип, наследующийся от него.

Если гипотетически предположить, что вам всё-таки удастся это нарушить, то получится, что в коде, который требует значение некоего базового типа (и использует у него тот метод, который вы перекрыли более ограниченным) не всякий более конкретный тип можно использовать.

Наследование получается неполным, и выходит, что система типов перестаёт контролировать, что наследующие типы применимы в коде для базового.

Comment: ну в С++ то на это пофиг) https://ideone.com/DDQN8q

Comment: @pavel в С++ вообще странное наследование.

Comment: кстати, используя smali код я в целом могу такое сделать и всё даже будет работать... Даже так как задумано (виртуальности пофиг на модификатор).

Comment: @pavel нет, как задумано, не получится. Приватный метод либо можно вызвать снаружи (и тогда сломалась приватность), либо нельзя (и тогда сломался принцип Лисков). Не вижу места для третьего состояния.

Comment: И понятно, что низкоуровневыми средствами можно много что отмочить. Да и не низкоуровневыми тоже: есть ведь рефлексия. Но это "запасные планы", когда основные дизайн-цели языка по каким-то причинам не стыкуются с сиюминутными требованиями конкретной задачи.